# Error after downloading HotTowel.Angular

Tags: angularjs, hottowel

I created an empty web solution, added an empty web application, used following NuGet command to download HotTowel.Angular template,

```
Install-Package HotTowel.Angular -pre
```

Executed the project and as soon as I run my web application it shows splash screen then, I get following error:-

```
{{VM.BUSYMESSAGE}}
```

Any idea why is that ?

Comment: plz elaborate?? it too vauge

Comment: Thats all really i am doing, created an empty web solution, added an empty web application, used above mentioned NuGet command to download that HotTowel.Angular template, executed the project andi am getting error {{VM.BUSYMESSAGE}} after showing splash screen. I am assuming angular is not recognizing this as angular tag and since i am pretty new to angular i dont know how to fix it

Comment: please use http://plnkr.co/ so that we can debug and fix your issue

Comment: Have you downloaded angular as well?

Comment: Yes this command Install-Package HotTowel.Angular -pre downloads everything that this template needs including Angular, bootstrap, jquery etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same error after updating to jQuery 2.1.3.  I do not get this error with the default template issued version of 2.1.1.

UPDATE: It turns out I forgot to change the version in the script reference to jQuery on the index.html page to match the library.  So check that out on your end and you should have your solution.

Comment: Yup, for some reasons, the jquery version is not correct by default in index.html, as soon as i changed to the correct version which is downloaded with the template, it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I tried both installing it via nuget package and package manager console. No Luck. Showing {{ VM.BUSYMESSAGE }} on screen. Error is showing $ is undefined. Looks like it is problem related to jQuery.

Unhandled exception at line 7, column 38 in scripts/bootstrap.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: ok good to know that...i am not the only one having this issue. I will try to find some time over the weekend and will try to fix the issue. Thanks for sharing your exp.

Comment: No Problem. I will try on my side. Please share if you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

index.html page contain:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

Check your jQuery version and update to

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.N.js"></script>

//In my case
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```